# Having trouble printing a chained Hashtable c++

Tags: c++, function, hashtable

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;
const int TABLESIZE = 3;

class HashTable
{
    public:
        string k;
        int v;
        HashTable* next;

        HashTable(string k, int v)
        { 
            this->k = k;
            this->v = v;
            next = NULL;
        }  
};

class HashMapTable
{
    private:
        HashTable **t;
    public: 
        HashMapTable()
        {
            t = new HashTable * [TABLESIZE];
            for (int i = 0; i < TABLESIZE; i++)
            {
                t[i] = NULL;
            }
        }

        int HashFunction(int v)
        {
            return v % TABLESIZE;
        }

        void Insert(string k, int v)
        {
            int hV = HashFunction(v);
            HashTable* p = NULL;
            HashTable* en = t[hV];
            while (en!= NULL) 
            {
                p = en;
                en = en->next;
            }
            if (en == NULL) 
            {
                en = new HashTable(k, v);
                if (p == NULL) 
                {
                    t[hV] = en;
                } else 
                {
                    p->next = en;
                }
            }   else      
                {
                    en->v = v;
                }
        }

        void PrintTable()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < TABLESIZE; i++)
            {
                
                if(t[i] != NULL)
                {
                    cout << t[i]->k << " " << t[i]->v << endl;
                }
            }
        }

        ~HashMapTable() 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < TABLESIZE; i++) 
            {
                if (t[i] != NULL)
                delete t[i];
                delete[] t;
            }
        }
};

int main()
{
    HashMapTable HT;
    cout << "entering the pairs now" << endl;
    HT.Insert("Boramir", 25);
    HT.Insert("Legolas", 101);
    HT.Insert("Gandalf", 49);

    cout << "printing the pairs now" << endl;
    HT.PrintTable();
}
```

My issue is that not all the key value pairs in the table are being printed depending on the table size. If it's 3 (the desired amount) only 2 print, but if it's at least 7, they all print? I'm not sure what piece of my code is causing this to happen. Also, if there are multiple pairs in one bucket, the second/third/etc pair doesn't print and I'm not sure why. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Looks like `PrintTable()` prints out only the first item in each chain.  You probably want it to walk the linked-list of each chain as well, so that any additional items in each chain will get printed too.

Comment: HashTable leaks memory because it lacks a destructor. Don't defer cleanup to other classes. It's also best to give it an insert, find, remove, replace, print method. It's also just a `std::list<std::pair<std::string, int>>`. `PrintTable()` should `std::cout << t[i] << std::endl;`, letting the `operator <<` of the `HastTable` deal with printing the whole list.